# SupportMapFragment - NullPointerException

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragment

Estoy cargando un fragment de mapas dentro de un bottom navigation. La plantilla creada por Android Studio hereda de un FragmentActivity, que lo cambie por Fragment para poder llamar el archivo en el bottom navigation. Cuando navego a dicho fragment me salta una excepcion NullPointerException y no se porque. En mobile_navigation todo esta en orden por eso no lo agrego.

---

Este es el fragment **Maps**, lo que me da error es esa llamada me devuelve null

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return view;
    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
```

---

Archivo **fragment_maps.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.maps.MapsFragment">


    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context=".ui.maps.MapsFragment" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

**Logcat**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.prueba.prueba, PID: 1806
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
        at com.prueba.prueba.ui.maps.MapsFragment.onCreateView(MapsFragment.java:34)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: El problema es que R.id.map no esta cargada en ningun lado cuando lo pedis, el xml al que pertenece simplemente no fue cargado y entonces lo va a encontrar.

Comment: @ErickSilva modifique la pregunta. Lo tengo implementado como dices si esta implementado en el mismo fragment pero me da error

Answer (score 0):

una pregunta estas implemtentado la clase OnMapReadyCallback en tu Activity o Fragment. 
Por ejemplo

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Deberas implementar la funcion `public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap{}`

Comment: Si lo tengo implementado. El error es cuando casteo el fragmento que ves en el xml

Comment: Yo lo que qiero es que extienda de un fragmento no de un fragmentActivity me entiendes

Comment: Podrias agregar el error del Logcat @AlexRivas

Comment: Ya agregué el logcat. Mira ver si puedes ayudarme @Carlosgub

Comment: Disculpa por la demora, podrias poner mapFragment.getMapAsync("tu contexto aca") porque creo que estas referenciando a otro contexto que no es el del fragmento

Comment: Podrias sacar el @Nullable de tu onCreateView